# How to pass value from one form to other datagrids form

Tags: c#, winforms

[When I click on button "Adicionar"(add) opens new form (Picture 2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DAMrY.png)

[I got all combobox and textbox's filled.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0LMuA.png)

My question is, I click on button "Confirmar", how can I put this values  from - "Produto", "Preço Unitário", "IVA" and "Quantidade" in 1st picture datagrid?

I don't know how to do it, if you guys can help, I'll appreciate it.

Thank you :)

Comment: Combobox Name ("ASDAS") - cbproduto;
Preço Unitário Name ("15,2") - txtpreco;
IVA Name ("23") - txtiva;
Quantidade Name ("1") - txtquantidade;
Confirmar Name - btnconfirmar; 
DataGrid Name - dataGridView1;

Answer (score 0):

It depends upon the way you are doing. If you are saving the data in some storage like in database or text file or any other storage, then you can get the data from respective resource and can load the load in the datagridview.

E.g. : dgv.DataSource = Get data from source

If you are saving the data in global memory(like `public static property` to hold data), you can get data from that global memory and load that into the datasource of datagridview.

If you can share your code, how are you doing, We can suggest you some concrete implementation.

Comment: I don't have any kind of code to that, just got to another things, like fill combobox and text box, and don't know how I can do it